# Use 3d model as icon without scaling in Google Earth Plugin

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

There're two types of objects we can place on the google earth.

The first one is 3d models - they have real size and they scale with dependency on the camera position.

The second one is icons and labels - they overlay the map and do not scale while the camera moves.

So is there a possibility to use 3d models like icons? That means I want to switch my png-icons with beauty 3d-models that do not scale and that have icon's behavior.

I know that there's access to the camera and object positions, and we can rescale 3d object with dependency on the distance every time when the camera or an object moves, but I believe there's simpler way without all these calculations and observables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say no, there is no simple way to achieve this.

As you say, an icon doesn't have any geometry other than a location, but a 3D model is specifically defined by its location and its length, width, height, etc. Yes you could calculate the scaling and attempt to redraw the model based on the current view, but that wouldn't be trivial and I really doubt that the results would be very pleasing.